# Is there Automation Account selector available when creating UI definition for Managed Application?

Tags: azure

I am attempting to create a managed application and in the process of defining template and createUIdefinition. The application requires automation account and I am unclear on how it can be achieved. Documentation indicates the controls available for defining portal UI have Storage Selector. Is there something similar that will allow me to define a blade for selecting or setting up the automation account.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such a selector. These are all the available functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-elements